# excel into word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

How can I paste an excel table that goes over two or more pages into word? (going also over two pages!)
I know the usual method copy - paste special - enhanced metafile, but that is just with one page, then I usually hide the other lines and copy again. But there must be a better way, right?

Comment: A better way to do what? You can't fit a mountain through a keyhole! And if you have too much data for a page, that's it really! Either make the excel table as small as possible, switch to landscape or print it out and stick the sheets together (or print to an A1 printer!)

Comment: @Dave Rook, do exactly that: paste an excel table that goes over two or more pages into word, of course embedded in word with headers, footers, ref. etc…I don’t think your comment was neither useful nor respectful. I found another way which could interest others: make a pdf from excel and then save it as .tiff. This will create a picture per page that you can insert in word, without having to hide lines and copy paste page for page. 
This works nicely but again, I’m sure there are people out there with more experience and knowledge than me that might come up with a better way to do the work!

Comment: So, may be I miss-understood. But if you make your Word file lanscape, then you can paste it over several pages?

Comment: Sure I do paste it either portrait or landscape, depending on the table to ensure readability. The wonderful solution for me would be to be able to paste excel in word while the pages (excel is divided in pages already) are respected. But as it doesn't work like that, so I have to make a pdf and then tiff which makes the pages isolated or carefully hide lines and copy just the data that can fit one page and then paste it :(

Comment: I don't think this is possible. [It has been asked before](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-word/import-multi-page-excel-file-into-word-maintaining/6c4edb0d-897b-4b63-bb0f-7de7a9ba7a28?msgId=a76e7b21-0e67-4756-9ac5-90c598ebbe06)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not sure either if there is a simple way, but I think the pdf/tiff method works better for me than the guys way on the link. But I remain hopeful, that somebody will find a better way. Maybe future programmers in Microsoft?? Thanks for trying anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you will fit it in a word on single page is to scale it.

It will become difficult to read but not distorted.

Better alternative is to paste it as LINK in Word document.